# unable to install packages bc i cant build wheel for pil or pillow

Tags: python, package

"Could not build wheels for Pillow, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects"
this is the error it gives every time I try to install most packages including pillow. i checked and I don't have pillow nor pil but for some reason I cant reinstall them either. if it helps i am running python 3.11

i have read the documentation on how to install pillow and removed pil, i have also checked and uninstalled pillow form my hard disk, if that was the problem but it didnt work. i have upgraded pip

Comment: Did you try to update wheel and setuptools? (run `python -m pip install --upgrade wheel setuptools`)

Answer (score 0):

Try install pillow with this command-line:

```
pip install --upgrade PILLOW
```

Comment: i have and it makes no difference

Comment: I had similar problem with Python 3.11, but I tried to use a 3.8 Python version. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

you can go to your project file,

go to the Lib folder in your Lib folder you will see site-packages, go to the site-packages, delete the pillow version that is conflicting with the package version that you are trying to install.

then pillows version 9.0.^ are supported by python 3.10.^, so you have to install python 3.10.1 in your env, to create the right environment then run

```
pip install Pillow==9.1.0
```

else if you are using python 3.11.^, this does not support Pillow version 9.1.0

so run `pip -m install Pillow` 
or `pip install --upgraded Pillow`